# always get error report of "NUMA memory tuning in 'preferred' mode only supports single node"

Tags: cpu, kvm, libvirt, numa

I am trying to tune VM CPU to a larger size, for example, **16** vCPU by editing the KVM domain XML file:

```
<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>bigip-2-10.250.100.102</name>
  <uuid>c978f323-9c61-4db4-bfc0-35e65f06bf05</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>8388608</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>8388608</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='auto'>16</vcpu>
  <numatune>
    <memory mode='preferred' placement='auto'/>
  </numatune>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-rhel7.0.0'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
```

When I shut down and start the VM again. I got this error report:

`error: internal error: Process exited prior to exec: libvirt:  error : internal error: NUMA memory tuning in 'preferred' mode only supports single node`

However, when I change the vCPU size to **9** or change the  mode tag to `strict`. The VM can be started again. I get a bit lost, why it behaves like this way?

My machine numa info is as below:

```
[root@localhost ~]# numactl --show
policy: default
preferred node: current
physcpubind: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
cpubind: 0 1
nodebind: 0 1
membind: 0 1

[root@localhost ~]# numactl --hardware
available: 2 nodes (0-1)
node 0 cpus: 0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30
node 0 size: 65029 MB
node 0 free: 6220 MB
node 1 cpus: 1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31
node 1 size: 65536 MB
node 1 free: 24109 MB
node distances:
node   0   1
  0:  10  21
  1:  21  10
```

The error said `NUMA memory tuning in 'preferred' mode only supports single node`

The single numa node 0 (single node) of the machine has 16 CPUs, why cannot it start a **16** CPUs (or even 10 CPUs) numa **preferred**  mode VM in the machine?

Why the maximum CPU number of numa preferred mode is **9**? is it relative to the VM images?

Anyone could help explain a bit, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I've been also struggling with this.
**The solution is to change memory mode from 'preferred' to 'interleave'.** Most probably the problem with preferred mode is that in conjuction with placement mode 'auto', numad sometimes uses a set of nodes instead of a single node (when there are not enough resources available in one). Actually libvirt IMHO should prevent this and force numad to always choose a single node but it doesn't. On the other hand, sometimes choosing one node only might not be possible (eg. there is not enough memory available on each of them). Therefore, the only solution to prevent libvirt errors: "NUMA memory tuning in 'preferred' mode only supports single node" is actually to use the 'interleave' mode. Accordingly to https://h50146.www5.hpe.com/products/software/oe/linux/mainstream/support/whitepaper/pdfs/a00039147enw.pdf:
"When node memory overflow occurs, interleave mode behaves like the preferred mode. That is, interleave mode selects a node from which to
allocate a page, and if that node has no available memory, the allocation is allowed to overflow to another node."
I really recommend reading all the stuff in the mentioned pdf starting from page 26. This should most likely answer all your questions regarding the subject.